# Capture incoming packets on port opended by other application

Tags: c#, .net

I'm considering interfacing my application with my VOIP system. My VOIP comes with client application that registers with the VOIP server and when acall comes the app displays call info on computer's screen. I identified local port that listens to the VOIP server. I identified the packet that contains the phone number of incoming call. I identified hex position of that phone number within the packet. So now I want to listen on the Socket for a Stream and create an event when expected packet comes. There are two questions:

1. Will Windows allow me to listed to packets coming on a port opened by another application?
2. I've never written Socket listener code. Can you refer me to an example or a tutorial?

Comment: You will only be able to do this by writing a network driver or by injecting your code into the other app. Both are hard propositions.

Comment: Or by using a packet capture library like pcap, using a managed API like SharpPcap. But please show some research effort.

Comment: well, the short answer is yes.. but there are other considerations. Like whether the VOIP client app is running, or can be run, in an emulated environment.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to create a man-in-the-middle application:

```
Client Application <----> Your Application <----> VOIP Server
```

Your application will act as a proxy between the Client Application and the VOIP server and at the same time do whatever it wants with the data.